# Making visualiser for music from Spotify

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I would like to know if there is a way to do a music visualiser for music streamed from Spotify on web. I can use NodeJS server too if necesery.

From what I have seen till now, there isn't any way to stream music to web. There are ways to stream to iOS and Android hoverer. There are ways to get informations about a song, and a way to get it's preview for about 30s, but I would like more.

No is totally acceptable answer.

Comment: You need to look into how spotify streams the music on web. If they just use a normal audio stream and not custom script, it gets really hard.

Comment: And do they have any kind of API?

Comment: i don't think that 'spotify web' has it's own api. Like i said, have a look into the code on the 'spotify web' page.

Comment: This will not work...

Comment: Ok. First of all: you mean that you want to make a visualizer which streams the music **from** the spotify web page. You can totally do that with NodeJs, but this is a little complicated. You need to get the spotify page with node and get the stream url. Then you need to implement a streamreader and you got it. Now you can play the stream and visualize what you get.

Comment: This seems amazing, could you show me how to "redirect" the stream? I have never done anything like this...